# Is it possible to change string into class with some function or command?

Tags: python, string, class, python-2.7, python-3.x

As in title. I want to know if is it possible to change string into class and link it with it. Example of what I have in mind:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, name, variable):
        self.n = name
        self.v = variable

tempclass = Example("tempclass", 1)
class1 = Example("class1", 2)
inpt = raw_input()
inpt()
stringtoclass = None

def function1():
    stringtoclass = "%s" % (inpt)
    ## function that change string into link to specific class and gives 
    print stringtoclass.v
```

Comment: `tempclass` does not represent a class: it is a variable/binding. `Example` is a class. So what is *really* desired?

Comment: do you want to get the instance of class or the class itself? Can you explain what you want a bit more?

Comment: Where did you get the string from?

Comment: @Anand S Kumar I'm new to programming I don't know what's the difference

Comment: @Gunnm You should ask us how to help with what you *actually* wanna do, not how to write the solution you think you need. What are you using this code for? **Edit:** In this case. Since you're clearly not sure what you should do

Comment: @Markus Meskanen I think that if I'll start explaining what I exactly want this for will only make everything even more confusing. Basicly I want to make function that adjusts one variable changes it into class and then use subclasses of it fe. if stringtoclass = "tempclass": (some function) stingtoclass = tempclass print stringtoclass.n

Comment: You probably need serialization with `marshal` or `pickle`

Comment: Instead of thumbs down I'd like to know if this is possible to do or not. I think it's relatively clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use `dictionary` for this. Dictionary are `key:value` based data structures. You can use the string as the key and the class object as the value. Example -

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, name, variable):
        self.n = name
        self.v = variable

obj_dict = {}
obj_dict['tempclass'] = Example("tempclass", 1)
obj_dict['class1'] = Example("class1", 2)

def function1(obj_dict, stringforobj):
    obj = obj_dict.get(stringforobj)
    if obj is not None:
        print obj.v
    else:
        print "Notfound"

inpt = raw_input()
function1(obj_dict, inpt)
```

Comment: Thank you this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Anand S Kumar's answer is better, but if you anyway want to get global variable by it's name, you can use [globals() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

In your example it would be:

```
class Example:
        def __init__(self, name, variable):
        self.n = name
        self.v = variable

tempclass = Example("tempclass", 1)
class1 = Example("class1", 2)

inpt = raw_input()

stringtoclass = globals()[inpt]
print stringtoclass.v
```